# Binding a kendo grid with knockout 3.1

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm using the latest versions pf Knockout, Kendo and the Knockout-Kendo bindings, but I'm having trouble getting this simple example to bind.  I'd like to bidn the grid to the observable array.  I'd also like to bind the paging parameters to the corresponding observable properties in the model. What am I missing here that's preventing the grid from binding to the data correctly?  How so I bind the pager properties?

[Here's the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Steve5877/R7LN2/)

Here's the HTML code.

```
<div><h2>Names List</h2></div>

<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: names, rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl', useKOTemplates: true, paging: { pageSize: 3} }"></div>
<div id="pager"></div>

<script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>            
    </tr>
</script>

<script>
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

and here's the Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPageSize = ko.observable(3);
    self.selectedPage = ko.observable(1); 
    self.totalPages = ko.observable(); 

    self.names = ko.observableArray(["Fred", "Barney", "Wilma", "Betty", "Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]);
}
```

Comment: There is a typo here `self.names = ko.observableArray(["Fred", "Barney", "Wilma", "Betty", "Tom". "Dick", "Harry"]);` (`.` instead of `,` after `"Tom"`)

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the typo here and in the jsfiddle. Still have the same issues.

Comment: I have 404 on your libraries in the fiddle (maybe they are private?). I'll replace them with links from cdnjs.com and check

Comment: I moved your `ko.applyBindings` after your `ViewModel` function. Is this what you have? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/R7LN2/3/)

Comment: That's definitely in the direction I want to go. How do I get the paging to work?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put your `ko.applyBindings` after the `ViewModel` function.

As for the paging, the correct syntax is:

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: names, 
                             rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl', 
                             useKOTemplates: true, 
                             dataSource: { pageSize: 3 }, 
                             pageable: true  }"></div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/R7LN2/5/)

Comment: I appreciate you getting the sample code working. I see that its now limiting the display to the correct page size. But how do I get the page links to display?

Comment: Thanks, I was being thick. I was trying to use paging: true instead of pageable.  Last question: do you know how to bind the pageSize to my viewmodels selectedPageSize observable?

Comment: @SteveWash works with `pageSize: selectedPageSize()` but you don't get updates (do you need them?)

Comment: Thanks. Don't think I'll need them.